# Run GUI app in intellij idea

Tags: java, swing, intellij-idea, mouse-listeners, jform-designer

I'm new with intellij idea and jFormDesigner.
I want to test my application.
I added jFormDesigner file to my project, created form and added simple button and textarea. I added mouse click event for button, but I don't know how to test it.

Here is event handler:

```
private void startButtonMouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    resultTextField.setText("hello!");
}
```

Here is generated by intellij idea code:

```
public class SysJournalForm extends JFrame {
    public SysJournalForm() {
        initComponents();
    }

    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
    }

    private void startButtonMouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        resultTextField.setText("hello!");
    }

    private void initComponents() {
        // JFormDesigner - Component initialization - DO NOT MODIFY  //GEN-BEGIN:initComponents
        // Generated using JFormDesigner Evaluation license - Vadim Mirgorod
        scrollPane1 = new JScrollPane();
        resultTextField = new JTextPane();
        startButton = new JButton();
        stopButton = new JButton();

        //======== this ========
        Container contentPane = getContentPane();
        contentPane.setLayout(null);

        //======== scrollPane1 ========
        {

            //---- resultTextField ----
            resultTextField.setText("test");
            scrollPane1.setViewportView(resultTextField);
        }
        contentPane.add(scrollPane1);
        scrollPane1.setBounds(5, 5, 530, 295);

        //---- startButton ----
        startButton.setText("\u0441\u0442\u0430\u0440\u0442");
        startButton.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                startButtonMouseClicked(e);
            }
        });
        contentPane.add(startButton);
        startButton.setBounds(5, 305, 130, startButton.getPreferredSize().height);

        //---- stopButton ----
        stopButton.setText("\u043e\u0441\u0442\u0430\u043d\u043e\u0432\u0438\u0442\u044c");
        contentPane.add(stopButton);
        stopButton.setBounds(140, 305, 130, stopButton.getPreferredSize().height);

        { // compute preferred size
            Dimension preferredSize = new Dimension();
            for(int i = 0; i < contentPane.getComponentCount(); i++) {
                Rectangle bounds = contentPane.getComponent(i).getBounds();
                preferredSize.width = Math.max(bounds.x + bounds.width, preferredSize.width);
                preferredSize.height = Math.max(bounds.y + bounds.height, preferredSize.height);
            }
            Insets insets = contentPane.getInsets();
            preferredSize.width += insets.right;
            preferredSize.height += insets.bottom;
            contentPane.setMinimumSize(preferredSize);
            contentPane.setPreferredSize(preferredSize);
        }
        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(getOwner());
        // JFormDesigner - End of component initialization  //GEN-END:initComponents
    }

    // JFormDesigner - Variables declaration - DO NOT MODIFY  //GEN-BEGIN:variables
    // Generated using JFormDesigner Evaluation license - Vadim Mirgorod
    private JScrollPane scrollPane1;
    private JTextPane resultTextField;
    private JButton startButton;
    private JButton stopButton;
    // JFormDesigner - End of variables declaration  //GEN-END:variables
}
```

[image: intellij idea and jFromDesigner project]

When I click test form in jFormDesigner form works but events no. How to test events?

Comment: I used Netbeans before and no problems. Now I need to use intellij idea.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1):

for [JButton](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) is there better to use

1) [Swing Action](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) very scalable workaround for whole [Swing JComponents](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/index.html)

2) (most common) [ActionListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html)

because

3) I think that [MouseListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html) is wrong [Swing Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/index.html) for [JButton](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html)

Comment: Thanx for answr, but what I need to do in intellij idea?

Comment: same way, just as you added the MouseListener

Comment: Look now, what I need to select?

Answer (score 0):

**Why don't you test it with mocks?** There are a lot of mocking frameworks out there. You could use Mockito, JMock, JMockit and so on... Mockito would be a good start. If you want to actually simulate the GUI actions... That's a whole other area. **I suggest you mock it first, test it that way.**

Also, the form is not genereated by Intellij Idea, but JFormDesigner - which you could use to abstract the GUI, not tying it to a specific IDE - which is a great idea.

Also, if you are going to use a lot of Swing components, **I suggest you go with the MVC pattern** - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller - it should simplify testing, maintenence and generaly simplify your form.

Comment: Thanx, but why in Intellij Idea I can't run my GUI App like in NetBeans (with events and other things)?

Comment: You can. You have a plugin for JFormDesigner. The plugin is available on the http://www.formdev.com/jformdesigner/doc/ides/intellij-idea/ .

Comment: The plugin should simplify your development, but you CAN actually run the form - it's generated Swing code. Based on your picture, you could click "MouseListener". Take a look at this - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseAdapter.html. I think it's simpler to get your button working. Just ovveride the "mousePressed", and you'r ready to go!

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever marked de checkbox "Custom Create"? When you add custom code for the component, in this case the JButton, you have to mark this option in its Properties Inspector.